# Small lag after tapping the button

Tags: javascript, android, html, touchstart

This is my game - [my game](https://jsfiddle.net/vhzgLcqq/)

**The problem:**

When I'm inspecting the game in Google Chrome Developer Tools and clicking(tapping) the canvas (or buttons), it occurs small lag and then the car goes left or right. How can I resolve this problem?

(I want to make the game for mobile devices)

I tried:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

And I'm using `touchstart` events. But still nothing...

EDIT:

Ok I tried FastClick but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  FastClick.attach(document.body);

  document.getElementById("goleft").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
      superCar.speedX = -40;
  }, true)

  document.getElementById("goleft").addEventListener('touchend', function(){
      superCar.speedX = 0;
  }, true)

  document.getElementById("goright").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
      superCar.speedX = 40;
  }, true)

  document.getElementById("goright").addEventListener('touchend', function(){
      superCar.speedX = 0;
  }, true)

}, true)
</script>
```

Touch events are now in `<head>`

Comment: I don't think it's a problem. Because if I will delete touch events and buttons there's no lag.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know about the 300ms touch delay and that's why you've added `width=device-width`. However, this only works on modern versions of OSs/browsers. So if you're on old Android for example, it won't have any effect. (See this [chart](http://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/results/#suppressing-300ms-delay).)

That page goes on to suggest using [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) or [tap.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/tap.js) as a polyfill, so give one of those a try and see if that helps.

Comment: A tried to use FastClick but nothing happend. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong...